# Service Manager Recovery Tab

Tags: services

[image]
<sub>(source: [codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/715967/SetRecoveryOptions.PNG))</sub>

So to my understanding those failsafes are triggered if the service for some reason fails to start.
But are they also trigger if the service fails to start because she is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

> So to my understanding those failsafes are triggered if the service for some reason fails to start. But are they also trigger if the service fails to start because she is disabled?

If the service is disabled, it never attempts to even start, hence the reason it’s disabled

Comment: How can you be sure about that?

Comment: @Hghaaaaaaoua - I have been using Windows for 25 years and have read Microsoft books